# Как сделать поиск по ключевым словам?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

Пользуюсь [autocomplete typeahead twitter](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)
Ищу как сделать или добавить возможность поиска по ключевым словам

что бы при вводе ***гугл*** или ***пщщпду*** выводился **Google**

```js
var stocksData = [
        {
            "company_name": "Facebook",
            "code": "fb",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Google",
            "code": "goog",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Yahoo",
            "code": "yhoo",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Apple",
            "code": "aapl",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Royal Mail",
            "code": "rmg.l",
        },
     ];
    
    var stocks = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: stocksData
        });

function getStocks(q, sync) {
  if (q === '') {
    sync(stocks.all());
  } else {
    stocks.search(q, sync);
  }
}

        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            minLength: 0
        }, {
            name: 'stocks',
            displayKey: 'company_name',
            source: getStocks
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
            $('#typeahead').val(data.code);        
        });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>


<input class="typeahead" />
<input  id="typeahead" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в объект с данными для поиска, например свойство `search`, со всеми вариантами написания искомой фразы:

```
...
 {
    "company_name": "Facebook",
     "code": "fb",
     "search": ["Facebook", "Фэйсбук"] // итд..
 },
...
```

Также, соответственно, потребуется немного изменить `datumTokenizer`:

```
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
     return d.search; // наш массив с вариантми написания
},
```

В итоге получаем что-то такое:

```js
var stocksData = [{
    "company_name": "Facebook",
    "code": "fb",
    "search": ["Facebook", "Фэйсбук"]
  },
  {
    "company_name": "Google",
    "code": "goog",
    "search": ["Google", "гугл", "пщщпду"]
  }
];

var stocks = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return d.search; // наш массив с вариантми написания
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: stocksData
});

function getStocks(q, sync) {
  if (q === '') {
    sync(stocks.all());
  } else {
    stocks.search(q, sync);
  }
}

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength: 0
}, {
  name: 'stocks',
  displayKey: 'company_name',
  source: getStocks
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data) {
  $('#typeahead').val(data.code);
  console.log(data.code);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<input class="typeahead" />
<input id="typeahead" />
```

Comment: просто АТдуши спасибо)